# Read meta data from image file with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

Is there any way to read the metadata of an image file in an `<img>` tag using JavaScript?

Comment: None of the above answers answer the question. Exif is just part of the metadata. The package suggested only accesses exif meta data, not all the other (e.g. tiff, aux, xmp, etc) metadata stored in an image file.

Comment: Which metadata?

Answer (score 2):

No. You would have to download the image (e.g. using XmlHttpRequest) and parse the image yourself.

Comment: i dont understand why this was down voted, this is a direct answer, the above answer references a library that essentially does THIS

Comment: This answer feels rather: https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/how-to-draw-an-owl