# How do I extract the metadata of a local image in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, metadata

I would like to get the metadata of an image that a user drags and drops into a webpage. I have the drag and drop set up. However, the image isn't actually uploaded to a server. It's accessed locally. Can I still get the metadata from the image using Javascript? If so, how do I do this? What good libraries are there?

If not, do I absolutely have to upload the image in order to extract the metadata? What's the fastest way to upload an image in Javascript?

Comment: [html5 file api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)

Comment: I think this would help you,


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929356/read-meta-data-from-image-file-with-javascript

Answer (score 4):

There is a library: [ImageInfo - read image metadata with JavaScript](http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/08/imageinfo-reading-image-metadata-with.html). Between that and [local file access in HTML5](http://wizard.ae.krakow.pl/~jb/localio.html) you should be able to get it.

**UPDATE**
New link for the [imageinfo library](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/extensions/imageinfo/imageinfo/imageinfo.js).

Comment: The second link is giving "You don't have permission to access this resource."

Answer (score -5):

Basically, JavaScript cannot "touch" your local file, you just can do that using [HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) + JavaScript or using Flash ActionScript