# HTML5: get device camera information (focal length,...)

Tags: javascript, html

Is it somehow possible, in javascript, to retrieve technical information about the device camera, such as focal length?

NB: my goal is not to extract EXIF tags from an existing file (like in [Read meta data from image file with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929356/read-meta-data-from-image-file-with-javascript)) but to find information about the current device camera.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read meta data from image file with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929356/read-meta-data-from-image-file-with-javascript) - I believe this is what you are looking for. Because as you know focal length, iso, etc is stored in metadata

Comment: @Adjit I don't have any image file actually.

Comment: You're talking about a camera attached to the computer and/or handheld device?

Comment: @JamieBarker Precisely. I'm talking about the device's camera.

Comment: No. Chrome supports [choosing the camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610945/how-to-choose-input-video-device-for-webrtc) but with little provided information. Unfortunately for your case, access to external resources and devices via the browser is limited.

Comment: And you're only looking for solutions in the browser?

Comment: @nils Yes, definitely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I extract the metadata of a local image in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562372/how-do-i-extract-the-metadata-of-a-local-image-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coming to a Firefox browser near you (apparently in version 39):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices.

> The MediaDevices.enumeratedDevices() method collects information about
>   the media input and output devices available on the system.

Doesn't look like it will contain the information you want, but potentially will be available in the future. [W3C Editors Draft](http://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html#mediadevices).