# How to obtain image info of an image in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, properties, base64

So I have an image that when I do

```
 console.log(image);
```

This is what appears on the console,

```
Object {imageFormat: "image/jpeg", imageB64: "..gibberish..."}
```

What I want to be able to extract the dimensions of the image, size of the image so that I can do conditionals and send it to a server.

I did something like this.

```
console.log(image.naturalHeight + " x " + image.naturalWidth);
```

but all I get is

```
 undefined x undefined
```

Take note that I also need the size please.

Just started to pick up Javascript so some terms may be unknown to me, please be kind with your comments.

tl;dr, how to obtain image properties?

Comment: Is the image fully loaded, what browser are you using?

Comment: like this? https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js (could not find any docs), [answer from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929356/read-meta-data-from-image-file-with-javascript)

Comment: @epascarello yes fully loaded, and after some cropping. The image is taken from a camera and is in base64.

Comment: @Barthy not really sure what metadata and exif is.. How is this helpful btw? :)

Comment: Well metadata is just a fancy word for properties in this case (I think) and exif is something that will help you extract them from the images.